# how to split the fallowing string into the key and value pair ?

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have a following string and in that I need to convert particular values in key, value pair

```
--Wj0WGWaKTUC0ynTbTxQl8Azz //this value is changing every request
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="key"

donny/uploads/11.txt
--Wj0WGWaKTUC0ynTbTxQl8Azz
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="acl"

private
--Wj0WGWaKTUC0ynTbTxQl8Azz
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Content-Type"

text/plain
--Wj0WGWaKTUC0ynTbTxQl8Azz
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="AWSAccessKeyId"

12345
--Wj0WGWaKTUC0ynTbTxQl8Azz
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Policy"

eyJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjogIjIwMTUtMDQtMDFUMDA6MDA6MDBaIiwNCiAgImNvbmRpdGlvbnMiOiBbIA0KICAgIHsiYnVja2V0IjogIm9uZWF3c3Rlc3QifSwgDQogICAgWyJzdGFydHMtd2l0aCIsICIka2V5IiwgImRvbm55L3VwbG9hZHMvIl0sDQogICAgeyJhY2wiOiAicHJpdmF0ZSJ9LA0KICAgIFsiZXEiLCAiJENvbnRlbnQtVHlwZSIsICJ0ZXh0L3BsYWluIl0sICAgDQogICAgWyJjb250ZW50LWxlbmd0aC1yYW5nZSIsIDAsIDEwNDg1NzZdDQogIF0NCn0=
--Wj0WGWaKTUC0ynTbTxQl8Azz
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Signature"

FCCjX7n+MKc4XmRvAt05f3Zk9Vk=
--Wj0WGWaKTUC0ynTbTxQl8Azz
```

in that above I need two values one is Name="Key" value and another one is after next line value

like fallwoing formate

```
"key" donny/uploads/11.txt

"acl" private

"Content-Type" text/plain

"AWSAccessKeyId" 12345

"Policy" eyJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjogIjIwMTUtMDQtMDFUMDA6MDA6MDBaIiwNCiAgImNvbmRpdGlvbnMiOiBbIA0KICAgIHsiYnVja2V0IjogIm9uZWF3c3Rlc3QifSwgDQogICAgWyJzdGFydHMtd2l0aCIsICIka2V5IiwgImRvbm55L3VwbG9hZHMvIl0sDQogICAgeyJhY2wiOiAicHJpdmF0ZSJ9LA0KICAgIFsiZXEiLCAiJENvbnRlbnQtVHlwZSIsICJ0ZXh0L3BsYWluIl0sICAgDQogICAgWyJjb250ZW50LWxlbmd0aC1yYW5nZSIsIDAsIDEwNDg1NzZdDQogIF0NCn0=

"Signature" FCCjX7n+MKc4XmRvAt05f3Zk9Vk=
```

thanks in advance

purna

Comment: I strongly suspect you'll find there's a header which specifies the part separator in each message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static KeyValuePair<string, string>[] ExtractInfo(string text)
{
    return Regex.Matches(text, @"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""(?<name>.*)""(\r?\n){2}(?<value>.*)")
                .Cast<Match>()
                .Select(m => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(m.Groups["name"].Value, m.Groups["value"].Value))
                .ToArray();
}
```

Explanation and demo:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="(?<name>.*)"(?:\r?\n){2}(?<value>.*)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/hcnXPyOAL15Y_gSP)